# Does number.charAt() work on hexadecimals too?

Tags: java, string, integer

Currently working with Java and wondering how to convert a string that represents hexadecimals into integers? Will number.charAt() suffice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) where the second argument is the radix.

```
int v = Integer.parseInt("A1", 16);
```

if you actually need to parse hex digits you could use [`Character.digit(char, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) where the second argument is (again) a radix

```
int v = Character.digit('a', 16);
```

Comment: this is most certainly the correct answer, but what's the difference between a hex digit and a string that reperesents a Hex number?

Comment: How is 234 like the number 2? The second is the first digit of the first.